# Java why a Map of Map (ex: Map<String,Map<String,String>>) not serializeable

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, sonarqube

We are using `HashMap` in `JDK 1.7` and I face some issue during the code review with **SonarQube**.

Please consider below samples:

```
public class SerializationTest implements  Serializable {

   private Map<String,String> test1=new HashMap<>(); //Serializeable
   private Map<ANEnum,String> test2=new HashMap<>(); //Serializeable
   private Map<String,ASerializeableObject> test3=new HashMap<>();  //Serializeable 

   private Map<String,Map<String,String>> test4=new HashMap<>(); //Not Serializeable
   private Map<ANEnum,Map<String,String>> test5=new HashMap<>(); //Not Serializeable
   private Map<String,Map<String, ASerializeableObject>> test6=new HashMap<>(); //Not Serializeable
```

The Sonar mark last three `HashMap`s as not `serializeable`. The Sonar error is (`Make "test4" transient or serializable`)

As far as I guessed the `HashMap` is `serializeable` if its key and value are `serializeable`. But it seems that if I set a `HashMap` value as another `HashMap`, the original `HashMap` will not be `serializeable` at all.

Is this Sonar Issue correct ?! If it is how can I fix it ?!

Comment: To test if something is serializable, serialize it. Sonar can't know if what your map actually contains at runtime is serializable. And if you ask about a Sonar violation, post the exact and complete message and rule name.

Comment: Rather poor effort on Sonarqube's part, given that the variable is declared and initialized in the same statement.

Comment: @EJP SOnar can't *guarantee* that the map is serializable, since it contains instances of `Map`, and `Map` isn't Serializable. At runtime, it might be, but at compile time, you have no guarantee that the inner maps are serializable.

Comment: @JBNizet The rule name is:  `Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable` (squid:S1948 ).

Comment: Dear @JBNizet it seems that for three first example, the Sonar guarantee the serialization, as you will not see a bug report there :) This may be a bug in sonar. Because, Sonar guarantees that `Map<String,ASerializeableObject>` is serializeable (You will see no error in code review) ,  but when you replace that `ASerializeableObject` with `Map<String,ASerializeableObject>` which is already mentioned to be `serializeable`, the final result `Map<String,Map<String,ASerializeableObject>>` is marked to be not `serializeable`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's see each line, one by one:

```
private Map<String,String> test1=new HashMap<>();
```

The key type, String, is serializable. The value type, String, is serializable. The concrete Map type, HashMap, is serializable. So everything is serializable.

```
private Map<ANEnum,String> test2=new HashMap<>();
```

The key type, ANEnum, is serializable. The value type, String, is serializable. The concrete Map type, HashMap, is serializable. So everything is serializable.

```
private Map<String,ASerializeableObject> test3=new HashMap<>();
```

The key type, String, is serializable. The value type, ASerializeableObject, is serializable. The concrete Map type, HashMap, is serializable. So everything is serializable.

```
private Map<String,Map<String,String>> test4=new HashMap<>();
```

The key type, String, is serializable. The concrete Map type, HashMap, is serializable. **But** the value type, Map, is not **necessarily** serializable. Some concrete implementations of Map (like HashMap), are serializable. Some others are not. So Sonar can't guarantee that this field is serializable, and issues a warning. If you're sure that you will only store serializable maps as values, no problem. If you store non-serializable maps, then the serialization will fail at runtime.

```
private Map<ANEnum,Map<String,String>> test5=new HashMap<>(); //Not Serializeable
```

Same explanation as before

```
private Map<String,Map<String, ASerializeableObject>> test6=new HashMap<>();
```

Same explanation as before

Remember that Sonar is only a tool, which can sometimes help, and sometimes get in the way. You should be in control, and decide if a warning should make you change things, or not.

Comment: _Some concrete implementations of Map (like HashMap), are serializable. Some others are not ...._ This is what I didn't  know! Thanks!